# Showing continuity of $\dfrac{xy(x-2y)}{x^2+y^2}$ at the origin.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> Show that the function $f(x, y)=\dfrac{xy(x-2y)}{x^2+y^2}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

It is easy to show continuity of $f(x, y)$ at points other than the origin but how is it continuous at the origin?

Comment: Hint: Switch to polar coordinates, i.e. $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$.

Comment: Can you give the value of $f(0,0)$?

Comment: As it stands, $f$ cannot be continuous at the origin because it is not _defined_ at the origin. What is the value of $f$ at the origin?

Comment: The book does not give any value but I guess they missed to define $f(0, 0)=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\Big|\dfrac{xy(x-2y)}{x^2+y^2}\Big|=\Big|\dfrac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}-\dfrac{2xy^2}{x^2+y^2}\Big|\leq|y|+2|x|$$

Answer (score 1):

$$0\leqslant \frac{|xy(x-2y)|}{x^2+y^2}\leqslant \frac{(x^2+y^2)|(x-2y)|}{2(x^2+y^2)}=\frac{|x-2y|}{2} \to 0 \;\mbox{ as } (x, y)\to (0,0).$$
If $f(0,0)=0$, then $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$. Otherwise, $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: @Christian Blatter Oh I see, I edited, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [Shinja's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2233522/showing-continuity-of-fx-y-at-the-origin#comment4592605_2233522):

$$f(x, y)=\dfrac{xy(x-2y)}{x^2+y^2}=r\cos\theta\sin\theta(\cos\theta-2\sin\theta)$$

Now, $\cos\theta\sin\theta(\cos\theta-2\sin\theta)$ is bounded between, say $A$ and $B$.

Then, $Ar \le f(r,\theta) \le Br$.

Squeezing with $r\to0$ gives $f(r,\theta)\to0$ as required.

Comment: Note: I cannot find the exact forms of $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score -1):

The function $f(x,y)$ is undefined at the origin, hence, it is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Note that it does not have a limit as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ because the limit of $f$  is different depending on the path that $(x,y)\to (0,0)$. For example,

$$ \lim_{y\to0} f(0,y) = -2$$
$$ \lim_{x\to0} f(x,0) = 1$$

Comment: $\displaystyle \lim_{y\to0} f(0,y) = \lim_{y\to0} \frac {0y(0-2y)} {0^2+y^2} = \lim_{y\to0} \frac {0} {y^2} = 0$

Comment: @DHMO, thanks for your correction.